# Recursive function behaves unexpected

Tags: php

I have a function where - based on parent-child id's - results are retrieved from the database. The parent-child structure can contain up to four 'levels' of hierarchy and based on a given scenario results from the deepest level should be retrieved from a given level.

I have this function:

```
static public function ThisFunction($iParentId, $aResult) {

    $aRows = ClassName::GetAllByParentId($iParentId);

    for($i = 0; $i < count($aRows); $i++) { 

        $oRow = $aRows[$i];

        if($oRow->Level != 'deepest_level') {

            return ClassName::ThisFunction($oRow->Id, $aResult);
        } else { 

            $aResult[] = $oRow;
        }
    }

    return $aResult;
}
```

In my framework database-calls (in this case ClassName is a Model_TableName) are made statically. ThisFunction refers to - as you can see, this function.

The result is that results are being looped, but when for the first $aRows iteration 'deepest_level' has been processed all rows from that parent, the function stops. It is my expectation the function would go back to its recursive calls and process the other data all the way down.

Am I overseeing something on this lazy sunday?
Thanks in advance.

**Edit**
I've tried the suggestions but I'm still stuck with my initial problem. Say I have this sample dataset:

```
id  parent id   level   value
-----------------------------
1   0           highest AAA
2   1           middle  BBB
3   1           middle  CCC
4   2           deepest DDD
5   3           deepest EEE
6   0           highest FFF
```

This dataset has fewer levels, but its just to demonstrate.

When I'm looking for the deepest values I'm expecting to get `DDD` and `EEE`. In my case I only get `DDD`. Also when I try to merge the results...

Comment: Funny. Looks like you are building a family tree, like I am doing just now.

Comment: It's not a family tree, it's a location based tree (country, state, city and so on). But for the readability I've just mentioned the basics :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the level is not the deepest, you return from the recursive call immediately, and don't process the other elements in the loop.

I guess you meant:

```
$aResult[] = ClassName::ThisFunction($oRow->Id, $aResult);
```

or something similar.. from your question it's impossible to tell how the result should look like.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, sorry for the late reaction. Problem has been solved using your suggestion. +1

Answer (score 3):

You never merge the results of your nested calls but simply return them. Try changing

```
return ClassName::ThisFunction($oRow->Id, $aResult);
```

to

```
$aResult = array_merge($aResult, ClassName::ThisFunction($oRow->Id, $aResult));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, sorry for the late reaction. Problem has been solved. +1

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you want to collect results of recursive calls?

```
$aResult[] = ClassName::ThisFunction($oRow->Id, $aResult);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, sorry for the late reaction. Problem has been solved. +1